# Notice: Undefined variable: Genero in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line

Tags: php

hola soy nuevo talvez me puedan ayudar con este problema  ME SALE ESTOS ERRORES:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Generos in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: Genero in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: video in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: pag in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: en in C:\Users\santiago\Desktop\USBWeb\root\index.php on line 24
```

LOS CODIGOS SON ESTOS

```
 <?php
// ejemplo pagina modular
//Primero recibimos las variables
$Generos=$_GET['Generos'];

//Preguntamos si $Generos esta vacio [es decir si no se especifico algun genero]
if($Generos==NULL) //NULL quieire decir "Nulo o Vacio"
{
    //si esta vacio le asignamos un genero por defecto.
    $Generos="Principal";
}

//Para hacer las cosas mas faciles:
$dir_gen="Generos/"; //especifica la carpeta donde esta las listas de generos.Fijate en el "/".
$ext=".php";//extension de la listas

//Algunas opciones extras :D
$Genero=ucwords($Genero);//Pone en mayuscula la primera letra; lo uso solo para una mejor presentacion :)
$titulo="theoscarvip -".$Generos; //Para el titulo.

$video=$_GET['video'];
$pag = $_GET['pag'];
$en = $_GET['en'];
$sel = rand(0,11);
$bus = array("Vico c","Rakim y Ken-Y","Eddy Lover","factoria","Divino","Don Omar","Niga","Chapa c","joel y randy","Arkangel","Miguel angel","Wisin y yandel");
if ($video==""): {$video=$bus[$sel];} endif;
if ($pag==""): {$pag=1;} endif;
if ($en==""): {$en="youtube";} endif;

//Bueno esto seria lo mas basico para empezar un web modular con PHP. seguimos....
?>


<?
//Ahora mostramos la lista

//primero preguntamos si el genero existe
if(file_exists($dir_gen.$Generos.$ext))//notese que especificamos la carpeta donbde esta las listas.
{
//si existe, entonces lo INCLUIMOS
include($dir_gen.$Generos.$ext);
}
else //en caso contrario [si no existe]
{
echo "Error: No se encuentra la lista de ".$Generos;
}

//Notas finales

//Cuidado con los nombres de las listas: "Reggaeton" no es lo mismo que "Reggaeton"
//Recomiendo Adobe DreamWeaver para codificar en PHP.
?>
```

Comment: El problema es que no está recibiendo los valores en el `$_GET` por ejemplo en la URL: `index.php?genero=texto&video=texto... etc`

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en que las variables no reciben ningún valor a través de `$_GET`, por lo tanto están vacías, estas al estar vacías ya dan un null desde el principio, dando lugar al mensaje de error, intenta meterle datos a través de un `<form></form>` de `HTML` por ejemplo. Saludos.